# Can't enter safe mode

Tags: windows-8.1, login, safe-mode, login-screen

I'm trying to enter safe mode, but the screen remains black and there's "safe mode" in 4 corners.

No sign-in option or what so ever appear after.

Normal mode says

> "the group policy client service failed the sign in access is denied"

so that why I tried to enter safe mode from the first place and give it a try to fix this.

This happens to my admin-user.

I'm using win 8.1 64 bit. If you need any other tech data just say.

Comment: What happens if you press Control + Alt + Delete?

Comment: nothing happens

Answer (score -2):

Pick up your windows install DVD/USB and choose repair.

Comment: Is this the same repair as without windows usb? I tried it and it failed :/ Also tried just now the system restore and it's failed too :/

Comment: System restore failed? Could you try a rescue disk such as Hiren's BootCD?

Comment: I don't know what is Hirens bootcd, but I found this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/at-the-opening-screen-i-got-the-message-policy/322256ab-81e1-4530-ae08-56d358c4f513  BUT I don't understand how to " associate the Value data GPSvc with it" in the "6" section. Can anyone help plz?

Comment: Can you create a new account and see if the error happens then?

Comment: Please provide more details, this is not helpful.

Comment: It is very important to make a rescue disk/USB-flash, at least once a week. If you don't care about doing this, nobody can help you. The best thing you can do is to carry your machine to the window and throw it out and promise yourself never to get a new one.